# What particles are closed strings?

Tags: particle-physics, string-theory, elementary-particles

In String Theory, I understand that gravitons are particles that are closed strings. Are there other particles that are manifested from closed strings?

Comment: @CuriousOne That kind of comment is really not helpful at all. Speculative physics is still physics. Would you have been against Higgs boson questions before 2012?

Comment: @Javier: I wasn't against the Higgs, at all, mostly because I was afraid that we would find it. The Higgs being where it is is the most boring physics result, ever. The important thing about the Higgs is, though, that it was a testable hypothesis. Strings don't even reach that level, so they don't even qualify for the "speculative" label.

Comment: Gravitons are not "particles that are closed strings", they are a particular massless state arising when one quantizes the string. There is a plethora of other states in the string spectrum that should be covered in every standard treatment of strings. I'm not sure what the question is.

Answer (score -1):

The heterotic group decomposes as $E_8~\rightarrow~SU(3)\times E_6$, The $\bf 248$ of the $E_8$ decomposes as
$$
{\bf 248}~\rightarrow~(\bf 8,~\bf 1) + (\bf 1,~\bf 78) + (\bf 3,~\bf 27) + (\bf\bar 3,~\bf\bar{27})
$$
We have here the $(\bf 8,~\bf 1)$ of $SU(3)$ which is identical in form to the irreducible representation used for gluons, or the old nonet theory of hadrons. However, this is not directly QCD in the standard sense. The $(\bf 1,~\bf 78)$ representation of the $E_6$ is one of the triplets transforming under $SU(3)$ with the complex $\bf 27$ dimensional representation of $E_6$. The adjoint representation of $E_8$ contains the adjoints of these subgroups so the 162 generators of the $(\bf 3,~\bf 27) + (\bf\bar 3,~\bf\bar{27})$ of $E_6$ transforms as triplets of $SU(3)$

Now let us look at the decomposition of the $E_6~\rightarrow SO(10)\times U(1)$ The two irreps of the $E_6$ decompose as
$$
{\bf 78}~\rightarrow~{\bf 45}_0 + {\bf 16}_{-3} + {\bf\bar{16}}_3 + {\bf 1}_0
$$
$$
{\bf 27}~\rightarrow~{\bf 16}_1 + {\bf 10}_{-2} + {\bf 1}_1.
$$
Further decompositions are then possible down to $SU(3)\times SU(2)\times U(1)$ The upshot is that all of the particles in the standard model can embed in the $E_6$, and ultimately into the $E_8$. The $(\bf 8,~\bf 1)$ connect with the graviton and the weights of the $E_8$ group.

The GUT model $SU(5)$ as well as $SO(10)$ have complicated $X^{1/3},~Y^{4/3}$ charged bosons that interchange quarks and leptons. The $E_6$ has much the same with more elaborate structure; it is considerably more involved than $SO(10)$. So as a result there are additional particles or states in these more complex gauge theories with exceptional groups.

Comment: And you don't need strings for any of that. Groups are groups.

Comment: There's a lot of fancy stuff going on here, but you never address the basic flaw of the question that gravitons are not strings, and I am rather puzzled why you would choose to decompose *one half* of the gauge group of the heterotic $E_8\times E_8$ string in order to talk about particle states in string theory. There are particles other than the graviton in all string theories, you don't need "more complex gauge theories" or exceptional groups at all.